How to create a custom task similar to the Sequence Container in SSIS?
I've been researching how to automatically export task sequence logs to logs or a database. I aim to automate this using a Sequence Container, but I'm stuck due to lacking access to the DLL file to understand the code and its internal workings. My idea was to use this Sequence Container as a reference for my own code, but without the DLL, I can't progress.
I used sql server 2016

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
